# Python Eve UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, rest, pycharm, eve

I'm trying to run basic eve application. There is an example on this page: http://eve.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html . I created project in PyCharm and these two .py files :
run.py

```
from eve import Eve
app = Eve()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

settings.py

```
DOMAIN = {'people': {}}
```

And I constantly get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/marti_000/BabyProjects/webApp/run.py", line 5, in <module>
    app.run()
   File "C:\Users\marti_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\eve\flaskapp.py", line 201, in run
    super(Eve, self).run(host, port, debug, **options)
  File "C:\Users\marti_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Users\marti_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 708, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "C:\Users\marti_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 670, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "C:\Users\marti_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 564, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "C:\Users\marti_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 476, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
  File "C:\Users\marti_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\marti_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Users\marti_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 1: 
invalid start byte
```

ps: I got Python 3.6 32-bit

Comment: did you install `eve` within a venv as recommended in the installation docs? What do you see when you run `pip list`?

Comment: i get this ---> https://i.imgur.com/KIWhNQC.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line : hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name) throws UnicodeDecodeError because my hostname is "Džida". I changed my hostname to name without special characters and now everything works fine.